# how to fire click event on cells of daragridview table in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, event-handling

event handler code.

```
    private void dataGridView2_Click(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)
            dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if (cell.Value=="sewagram express")
            {
                SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("select * from sewagram", con);
                DataTable dth = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
                da.Fill(dth);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dth;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I am want this code to be worked when cell is clicked...please help

Comment: Variable `cell` is ImageCell, however , you compare `cell.Value` to `string`. That's controdictory. (ImageCell have Image object as Value).

Comment: sir,so what should i do?

Comment: so which code should i write....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, `sewagram express` isn't value. That's column header text or column name.

You need change following part of code:

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell) dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
if (cell.Value=="sewagram express")
{
```

If "sewagram express" is header text, you change like below:

```
//     DataGridViewImageCell cell = 
//          (DataGridViewImageCell) dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText=="sewagram express")
{
```

if "sewagram express" is column name you change like following:

```
//     DataGridViewImageCell cell = 
//          (DataGridViewImageCell) dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
if (((DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource)).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName
         =="sewagram express")
{
```

What you should do belong to what is "sewagram express".

---

### Edited

You create DataTable with `DataAdapter.Fill()` for DataGridView , so you can get table name from TableName property of DataTable (datagridview's datasource), probably .

```
// DataTable dtSource = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
// sorry, you need check the tablename of datagridview2's datasource. I fixed.
DataTable dtSource = (DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource;
if (dtSource.TableName == "sewagram express")
{
```

---

### Edited

I had a typo in my previous post, and revised.

You need check `TableName` value of dataGridView2 (in other words clicked DataGridView ).
I write whole code again and append line to display MessageBox for checking TableName value.
Is displayed value in MessageBox expected one? or not?

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtSource = (DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource;
    MessageBox.Show(dtSource.TableName,"");  // check the value of TableName

    if (dtSource.TableName == "sewagram express")
    {
        SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("select * from sewagram", con);
        DataTable dth = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
        da.Fill(dth);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dth;
    }
}
```

Comment: sewagram express is an item in the table....and also it is a table name..so when i click on the cell it should show the table named as sewagram express in other datagridview...that code is written in if statement.

Comment: if ((DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName
         =="sewagram express")

Comment: I understand, both of "sewagram" and "sewagram express" are table name.

Comment: sorry, I have mistake for `Columns[e.ColumnIndex]`. I already fixed. And I append code to check with tablename, soon.

Comment: sir,what to do with Columns[e.ColumnIndex] now?

Comment: sir,when i clicking on "sewagram express" in the datagridview it is not firing the code written in if statement..i have tried all but its not working...please do help.

Comment: @user3247620 I edited my post again, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the `CellClick` event.

```
dataGridView2.CellClick += dataGridView2_CellClick;
```

Then define the event handler as follows:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell) dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (cell.Value=="sewagram express")
    {
        SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("select * from sewagram", con);
        DataTable dth = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
        da.Fill(dth);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dth;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir still its not working....it is not firing the code when i clicked the cell named as "sewagram express".

Comment: dear sir, for your kind information, the cell ought to be fired. You can check it by setting `breakpoint` on the `if` line, where you are trying to check whether the cell value is equal to `sewagram express`. But this will always fail because an `Image` field does not have `string` value. So you need to change your condition accordingly. BTW, another answer is already accepted. So best of luck ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sir,sewagram express is a string...anyways i want it should be clicked and some code must fired...nothing is happening with it...

Comment: no sir,there is no error in the code but its not working